# Format excel cells from text to numbers with 1 decimal place and '%' symbol

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below is my macro code that convers text to numbers in ever sheet of excel and leaves it with '%' symbol concatenated:

```
'Convert text to numbers with one decimal place
            With rng
                .Value = .Value 'Convert text to numbers
                For Each cell In .Cells 'Loop through each cell in the range
                    If Right(cell.Value, 1) = "%" Then 'Check if the value ends with a percentage symbol
                        cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1) / 100 'Remove the percentage symbol and divide by 100
                        cell.NumberFormat = "0.0%" 'Set the number format to display one decimal place and a percentage symbol
                        cell.Value = cell.Value 'Remove trailing zero
                    End If
                Next cell
            End With
```

This code converts text to numbers correctly but leaves with 2 decimal places instead of 1. So for values 6.3% it converts to 6.30%. Numberformat doesn't do anything. Any help on how to fix this?

Comment: Your code works well for me and the output is just 1 decimal place. IS there any other code that may  change the output? Did you Debug it with F8 to see the exact moment?

Answer (score 1):

Try add a `\` in line 7 so it would look like this instead

`cell.NumberFormat = "0.0\%" 'Set the number format to display one decimal place and a percentage symbol`

By adding a backslash `\` before the `%` symbol, you are escaping the symbol and telling Excel to treat it as a literal character instead of a placeholder for a number format code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, setting the numberformat to "General" and then converting Text to numbers, on top set the numberformat as 0.0% fixed the prob;em"

```
 'Convert text to numbers with one decimal place
            With rng
                .NumberFormat = "General"
                .Value = .Value 'Convert text to numbers
                .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
            End With
```